# Web Part Maintenance error

Tags: error

I have SharePoint site which was working fine. My site has custom page with custom visual web parts. Suddenly i am getting Web Parts Maintenance Page error when accessing my page. I tried to find any clues in SharePoint log files but i can't find out the reason for this error. Can anyone tell me the possible scenarios for this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reason can be thousand.
Are you using custom web parts?
What that does?

Usually into ULS log you have all the reason about errors.

I suggest to you to use something like this:
https://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/

or this:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer

to understand what's going on.

Comment: I am using custom web parts only. It just loads grid with data from database. I have checked using ULSViewer, but could not find exact reason. Do i need to consider all category and levels in log file?

Comment: Yes, btw are you use a dev env? if yes, you can debug your application

Comment: We are not getting this issue in our dev env. This issue occurs in production side and we have only sharepoint log files to find the issue.

Comment: do you have a stage env?

Comment: yes we have staging env..

Comment: no issue there?

Comment: no issues in staging env.. This error occurs only in pro env.

Comment: what does the web part?

Comment: Webpart just displays grid. Values for grid will be taken from list.

Comment: so the problem be that: you have no permission to access to the list or the list doesn't exist